# Fine tune Huggingface model without labels

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers

I read that Hugginface models [could be fine tuned](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/training)
In a section Train with PyTorch Trainer there is a code example:

```
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased", num_labels=5)
...
```

But if I want to fine tune a model that computes sentence similarity (e.g. [paraphrase-multilingual-mpnet-base-v2](https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers/paraphrase-multilingual-mpnet-base-v2)), which is a number between 0 and 1, what could be the `num_labels`? There are no labels in the model.
How `num_labels` should be specified in that case?

Answer (score 2):

When working on a classification task, the `num_labels` parameter is typically employed. Its main role is to append a classification head (commonly referred to as CLS head) atop the base language model (such as BERT or similar models) for the purpose of fine-tuning. However, if your objective is to extract the raw embeddings or representations from the input text, you should bypass initiating with `AutoModelForSequenceClassification`.

To achieve this, you can instead initialize the general `AutoModel` class from the transformers library, as shown below:

```
from transformers import AutoModel
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")
```

This approach ensures that you get the base language model without the additional classification head, hence the output of the `forward` method will be just the raw hidden representations by the language model.

Comment: Thank you for reply.  
Am I supposed to use class `transformers.Trainer` next?
I read quite a lot of articles about Huggingface fine tune today, but didn't find that anybody does fine tune for raw embeddings.  
Does it make sense?  
Actually my goal is to change cosine similarity between some phrases which means that embeddings for that phrases should be changed. And now I'm confused how to specify for fine tune that one pair of sentences should have cosine similarity close to 1, and others should have similarity close to 0. Do I need to write custom function `compute_metrics` for that?

Comment: Yes, after loading the model with `AutoModel`, you'll need to pass it to a `trasnformers.Trainer` for fine-tuning purposes. That's the modular way of fine-tuning that Transformers makes use of. Although, as you want to adapt the trainer to your specific needs, you'll need to inherit a Trainer class (say MyTrainer), and then override its `compute_loss(...)` function. `compute_metrics` is not involved in training process, rather on evaluation where you wanna compute a set of metrics on your validation set. I suggest taking a look at Huggingface's provided examples to get a vivid idea.